# MySQL trigger syntax error?

Tags: mysql

```html
delimiter ||
create trigger bins_chk
before insert on VEHICLE 
on each row
begin
 if (new.`Vehicle_type`= 'car') then
  if (new.`Tonnage` != null or new.`No_Seats` <> null) then
   signal sqlstate "45000"
    set message_text "Do not match!";
 elseif new.`Vehicle_type`= 'suv' then
  if new.`Tonnage`<>null or new.`Engine_size`<>null then
   signal sqlstate "45000"
    set message_text "Do not match!";
 elseif new.`Vehicle_type`= 'truck' then
  if new.`Engine_size`<>null or new.`No_Seats`<>null then
   signal sqlstate "45000"
    set message_text "Do not match!";
 end if;
end ||
delimiter;
```

where is the problem, I just do not know how to fix it.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'on each row begin if new. `Vehicle_type = 'car'`
>   then if new.`Tonnage <> null` ' at line 3

Comment: For each row not on each row

Comment: BUG!  `<>null` does not do what you think.  Change to `IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `FOR EACH ROW` instead of `ON EACH ROW` (see [CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html)).